# Facebook SDK PHP login "Bad Request"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, codeigniter-3

I am trying to create FB login with PHP.
The URL of my App is : http:// example.com.
The redirect URL is http:// example.com/login/facebook/

This is my code for creating login URL in http:// example.com:

```
    $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id'     => FB_APP_ID,
        'app_secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
    ]);

    $callback = 'http:// example.com/login/facebook/';
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['email'];
    $data['fb_url'] = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions);
```

I get an URL and set it to a link where user can click and login.

This is my code in redirect URL (http:// example.com/login/facebook/):

```
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => FB_APP_ID, // Replace {app-id} with your app id
        'app_secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    if (! isset($accessToken)) {
        if ($helper->getError()) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
            echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
            echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
            echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
            echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
        } else {
            header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
            echo 'Bad request';
        }
        exit;
    }
```

The code is from the example here - [FB SDK DOCS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login) ,
but I get this error:

> Bad request

and access token = NULL. 
Where is the error and how to fix ?

Comment: Javascript fb login is much easier. For this php approach, make sure you replaced the app id and secret, and that you are using session_start() at the beginning of both files. Also, you can try to add some validations fro here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login?locale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

I guess because GET parameters code and state are not accessible in the redirect page. Try to do a var_dump of $_GET in the redirect page and see if they are there.